# How to run a script before all jsamine tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jasmine, integration-testing

I want to start a server and run tests on its API with Jasmine.

For that I want to make sure that the server is setup and running before jasmine runs its tests.

Also I have a lot of tests, and I split them into mutliple files.

I dont want to particularly start the server in the beforeAll hook of each test file, as it leads to conflicts on the port the server is running.

I thought of 2 theoretical Solutions that I dont know how to do with Jasmine.

1. To have a global before/after script to the jasmine command which is executed before/after all test-files.
2. To have a way to import all test Files into on Jasmine file where I can do my setup in the beforeAll as we all know it. However I dont know how to properly import those files and it also makes them all dependent on my mainTest-file. Meaning I cant execute them singularly.

Additional Info:
Im in a node.js environment running a express-server and am testing its api (each route gets its test file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `helpers` configuration. The files in the helpers directory will be executed before running all the tests. For example:

Project structure:

```
.
├── .babelrc
├── .editorconfig
├── .gitignore
├── .nycrc
├── .prettierrc
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── jasmine.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── src
    ├── helpers
    │   ├── console-reporter.js
    │   ├── fake-server-setup.js
    │   └── jsdom.js
    └── stackoverflow
        ├── 60138152
        ├── 61121812
        ├── 61277026
        ├── 61643544
        ├── 61985831
        └── 62172073
```

`fake-server-setup.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');

beforeAll((done) => {
  const app = express();
  global.app = app;
  const port = 3000;
  app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
  app.listen(port, () => {
    done();
    console.log('server is listening on port:' + port);
  });
});
```

We store the `app` variable which we will use in each test file to the `global` variable.

`a.test.js`:

```js
const supertest = require('supertest');
describe('62172073 - a', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    return supertest(global.app).get('/api').expect(200);
  });
});
```

`b.test.js`:

```js
const supertest = require('supertest');
describe('62172073 - b', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    return supertest(global.app).get('/api').expect(200);
  });
});
```

`jasmine.json`:

```
{
  "spec_dir": "src",
  "spec_files": ["**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)"],
  "helpers": ["helpers/**/*.js", "../node_modules/@babel/register/lib/node.js"],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": true
}
```

Test result:

```sh
Executing 2 defined specs...
Running in random order... (seed: 03767)

Test Suites & Specs:
(node:54373) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental

1. 62172073 - bserver is listening on port:3000

   ✔ should pass (51ms)

2. 62172073 - a
   ✔ should pass (5ms)

>> Done!


Summary:

  Passed
Suites:  2 of 2
Specs:   2 of 2
Expects: 0 (none executed)
Finished in 0.085 seconds
```

Comment: Still need to check your approach and if it works I will accept your answer. All in all a very detailed, informative and overall good answer. Thank you.